# blocking semalt referrers with htaccess rules

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-referer, referrer-spam

I have implemented the following code to htaccess but are still seeing referrers from semalt, such as:

```
74.semalt.com
89.semalt.com
```

The code:

```
# Block visits from semalt.com
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://([^.]+\.)*semalt\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Any idea how these referrers are bypassing this rule (which I found online) and how I can fully prevent them?

Comment: Not sure but try this `RewriteEngine On    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://.*semalt\.com [NC]    RewriteRule (.*) http://www.semalt.com [R=301,L]`

Comment: Did you try with `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} \.?semalt\.com$ [NC]` ? This will match every `semalt` subdomains, even if your code should be working (maybe `http://` is not in referer ? That would be weird but that's the only reason i see it does not match your condition)

Comment: Just go to semalt.com and request to exclude your website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is how I got it to work:

```
# Block visits from semalt.com
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://([^.]+\.)*semalt\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.semalt.com [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code looks good, syntax checks out ok! I used these mod_rewrite methods:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http(s)?://(www\.)?semalt\.com.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http(s)?://(.*\.)?semalt\.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*semalt\.com\ [NC,OR]
```

or with the .htaccess module mod_setenvif

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer semalt.com spambot=yes
SetEnvIfNoCase REMOTE_ADDR "217\.23\.11\.15" spambot=yes
SetEnvIfNoCase REMOTE_ADDR "217\.23\.7\.144" spambot=yes

Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=spambot
```

I even created an Apache, Nginx & Varnish blacklist plus Google Analytics segment to prevent referrer spam traffic, you can find it here:

https://github.com/Stevie-Ray/referrer-spam-blocker/

Answer (score 2):

Here is an updated code for many of spam referral sites using regular expressions

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} (?:o-o-6-o-o|bestwebsitesawards|s.click.aliexpress|simple-share-buttons|see-your-website-here|forum.topic55198628.darodar|hulfingtonpost|ilovevitaly|priceg|blackhatworth|semalt.semalt|kambasoft|buttons-for-website|BlackHatWorth|7makemoneyonline)\.com [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} (?:lomb|lombia|econom|lumb)\.co [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} (?:cenoval|Iskalko)\.ru [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} (?:smailik|humanorightswatch)\.org [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} (?:ranksonic|savetubevideo)\.info [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ – [F]
</IfModule>
```

Hope someone find this usefull

Answer (score 0):

I tried all manner of these sample snippets from all over the web. None of them worked, and Semalt kept changing their domains and paths.
I suggest this which works great for me and has sane syntax. It will apply to any referrer path that contains the semalt.com string. *Note you need Apache 2.4 for this to work.* It can go in your .htaccess no problem, or in theory in your main Apache config.

```
<If "%{HTTP_REFERER} =~ /semalt.com/">
        Deny from all
</If>
```

Good luck!
Update: if this causes a 500 error you need to empower your .htaccess, in your main Apache config, in this example, I have my .htaccess in my web server root of /var/www/wordpress, so I have in my .conf:

```
<Directory /var/www/wordpress>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: Thanks Mr B...The solution I posted seems to be working so far. But Ill keep this in mind in case it doesn't down the road.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach for blocking the ever growing list of botnet hosts:

```
# Block Common Botnets
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer fbdownloader.com spambot=yes
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer descargar-musicas-gratis.com spambot=yes
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer baixar-musicas-gratis.com spambot=yes
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer savetubevideo.com spambot=yes
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer srecorder.com spambot=yes
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer kambasoft.com spambot=yes
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer semalt.com spambot=yes
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer ilovevitaly.com spambot=yes
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer 7makemoneyonline.com spambot=yes
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer buttons-for-website.com spambot=yes
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer econom.co spambot=yes
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer acunetix-referrer.com spambot=yes
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer yougetsignal.com spambot=yes
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer darodar.com spambot=yes

Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=spambot
```